# make is giving error make: *** No rule to make target `clean'. Stop

Tags: c++, c, macos, makefile

Hi I have a simple MakeFile that contains this in it:

```
clean:
    rm -f ex1
```

but when i run command `make clean`, i get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, its only 2 lines and the 2nd line is started with a TAB not Spaces. anybody have any idea? I am on Mac OS X 10.9.2

and I am actually trying to learn c and following this tutorial :http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex2.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MakeFile` should be named `Makefile`. Remove the capital F.

Comment: awesome , it worked. still 11 minutes to go before i accept the answer.

Comment: actually the name could be even `MakeFile`. Just you have to call make with `-f` param.